# DetachedCreteria Query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I have this code:

```
public List<News> selectNewsForPage(int firstIndex, int secondIndex, FilterForm filter) throws DAOException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<News> rezNewses = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(""
                + "select rownum, "
                        + "COUNTOFCOMMENTS, "
                        + "NEWS_ID, "
                        + "SHORT_TEXT, "
                        + "FULL_TEXT, "
                        + "TITLE, "
                        + "CREATION_DATE, "
                        + "MODIFICATION_DATE " 
                + "from ( select COUNT(COMM_ID) AS COUNTOFCOMMENTS, "
                                + "NEWS_ID, "
                                + "SHORT_TEXT, "
                                + "FULL_TEXT, "
                                + "TITLE, "
                                + "CREATION_DATE, "
                                + "MODIFICATION_DATE " 
                        + "from (select COMMENTS.NEWS_ID AS COMM_ID, "
                                    + "NEWS.NEWS_ID, "
                                    + "NEWS.SHORT_TEXT, "
                                    + "NEWS.FULL_TEXT, "
                                    + "NEWS.TITLE, "
                                    + "NEWS.CREATION_DATE, "
                                    + "NEWS.MODIFICATION_DATE " 
                             + " from COMMENTS RIGHT JOIN " + filterQueryMaker(filter)+ " NEWS ON COMMENTS.NEWS_ID = NEWS.NEWS_ID) " 
                      + "group by NEWS_ID, "
                                + "SHORT_TEXT, "
                                + "FULL_TEXT, "
                                + "TITLE, "
                                + "CREATION_DATE, "
                                + "MODIFICATION_DATE  order by 1 desc, 7) " 
                + "group by rownum, "
                        + "COUNTOFCOMMENTS, "
                        + "NEWS_ID, "
                        + "SHORT_TEXT, "
                        + "FULL_TEXT, "
                        + "TITLE, "
                        + "CREATION_DATE, "
                        + "MODIFICATION_DATE  HAVING rownum BETWEEN ? AND ? order by 1");
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, firstIndex);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, secondIndex);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            News news = new News();
            news.setNewsId(resultSet.getInt(AllNamesEnum.NEWS_ID.getValue()));
            news.setShortText(resultSet.getString(AllNamesEnum.SHORT_TEXT.getValue()));
            news.setFullText(resultSet.getString(AllNamesEnum.FULL_TEXT.getValue()));
            news.setTitle(resultSet.getString(AllNamesEnum.TITLE.getValue()));
            news.setCreationDate(resultSet.getDate(AllNamesEnum.CREATION_NEWS_DATE.getValue()));
            news.setModificationDate(resultSet.getDate(AllNamesEnum.MODIFICATION_DATE.getValue()));
            rezNewses.add(news);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException("DAOException in selectNewsForPage() method: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try{
            closeAll(connection, preparedStatement, resultSet);   
        } catch(DAOException e){
            throw new DAOException("DAOException at " + e.getMessage() + " in selectNewsForPage() method");
        }
    }
    return rezNewses;
}


private String filterQueryMaker(FilterForm filter) {
    StringBuilder filterGuery = new StringBuilder("") ;
    if(filter.getTags() == null){
        filter.setTags(new ArrayList<Tag>());
    }
    String resultTags = join(filter.getTags(), "\', \'");
    if(!filter.getTags().isEmpty() && "".equals(filter.getAuthor().getName())){
        filterGuery.append(" (SELECT * FROM NEWS INNER JOIN " 
                + "(SELECT NEWS_ID AS FILTER_TAG_NEWS_ID FROM " 
                + "(SELECT NEWS_TAG.NEWS_ID, TAG.TAG_NAME " 
                + "from NEWS_TAG inner join TAG ON NEWS_TAG.TAG_ID = TAG.TAG_ID) " 
                + "WHERE TAG_NAME IN (\'")
                .append(resultTags).append("\') "
                + "GROUP BY NEWS_ID) ON NEWS.NEWS_ID = FILTER_TAG_NEWS_ID) ");
    }
    if(filter.getTags().isEmpty() && !"".equals(filter.getAuthor().getName())){
        filterGuery.append(" (SELECT * FROM NEWS INNER JOIN " 
                + "(select NEWS_ID AS FILTER_AUTHOR_NEWS_ID " 
                + "from NEWS_AUTHOR where NEWS_AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID IN " 
                + "(select AUTHOR_ID from AUTHOR where AUTHOR.NAME = \'")
                .append(filter.getAuthor().getName())
                .append("\')) ON NEWS.NEWS_ID = FILTER_AUTHOR_NEWS_ID) ");
    }
    if(!filter.getTags().isEmpty() && !"".equals(filter.getAuthor().getName())){
        filterGuery.append(" (SELECT * from NEWS where NEWS_ID IN (" 
                + "SELECT FILTER_AUTHOR_NEWS_ID AS FILTER_AUTHOR_AND_TAG_NEWS_ID FROM " 
                + "(select NEWS_ID AS FILTER_AUTHOR_NEWS_ID " 
                + "from NEWS_AUTHOR where NEWS_AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID IN "
                + "(select AUTHOR_ID from AUTHOR where AUTHOR.NAME = \'")
                .append(filter.getAuthor().getName()).append("\')) " 
                + "INNER JOIN\n" 
                + "(SELECT NEWS_ID AS FILTER_TAG_NEWS_ID " 
                + "FROM ( Select NEWS_TAG.NEWS_ID, TAG.TAG_NAME " 
                + "from NEWS_TAG inner join TAG ON NEWS_TAG.TAG_ID = TAG.TAG_ID) "
                + "WHERE TAG_NAME IN (\'")
                .append(resultTags).append("\'))" 
                + "ON FILTER_AUTHOR_NEWS_ID = FILTER_TAG_NEWS_ID)) ");
    }
    return filterGuery.toString();
}


private String join(List<Tag> tags, String conjunction) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Tag tag : tags) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            sb.append(conjunction);
        sb.append(tag.getTagName());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Please, help me build the same DetachedCreteria Query. Because i'he confused((
As a result of these three methods have to collect one large sql query that I should be replaced by DetachedCreteria

Comment: I'm sorry, but don't expect anyone to read all that (for free).

Comment: @jarlh I tried to make a stupid attempt...may be unsuccessful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute SQL requests via Hibernate, so you don't need convert it to Criteria API.

**UPDATED**

Let's try to begin from query in method

```
filterQueryMaker(FilterForm filter)
```

You don't need the first and the second SQL part for the Criteria query in this method. Only the third one.

```
    "SELECT * 
      from NEWS 
        where NEWS_ID IN (
          SELECT FILTER_AUTHOR_NEWS_ID AS FILTER_AUTHOR_AND_TAG_NEWS_ID 
            FROM (
              select NEWS_ID AS FILTER_AUTHOR_NEWS_ID 
                from NEWS_AUTHOR 
                  where NEWS_AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID IN (
                    select AUTHOR_ID 
                      from AUTHOR 
                        where AUTHOR.NAME = \'" 
+ filter.getAuthor().getName() + "\')) 
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT NEWS_ID AS FILTER_TAG_NEWS_ID  
                    FROM ( 
                       Select NEWS_TAG.NEWS_ID, TAG.TAG_NAME 
                         from NEWS_TAG inner join TAG ON NEWS_TAG.TAG_ID = TAG.TAG_ID) 
      WHERE TAG_NAME IN (\'" + resultTags + "\')
    ) ON FILTER_AUTHOR_NEWS_ID = FILTER_TAG_NEWS_ID)"
```

You will add parts of the criteria query by checking conditions. I think you don't need so many subselects in this query, try to simplify this SQL using joins. And after that try to use Criteria API. May be me or others will be able to help you with this more simple SQL.

P.S. I wonder, why do you need `GROUP BY NEWS_ID` in the first SQL query in `filterQueryMaker(FilterForm filter)` method?

Comment: Unfortunately, i need use Criteria API :(

Comment: If you know how solve my problem, then help me please

Answer (score 0):

I'he wrote filterQueryMaker(Filter filter) method:

```
private DetachedCriteria getCreteriaForFiltering(FilterForm filter){        
    DetachedCriteria criteriaForNewsByAuthor;

    if ("".equals(filter.getAuthor().getName()) && filter.getTags().isEmpty()) {
        criteriaForNewsByAuthor = DetachedCriteria.forClass(News.class);
    } else {
        Iterator<Tag> iteratorTags = filter.getTags().iterator();
        DetachedCriteria criteriaForTag = DetachedCriteria.forClass(NewsTag.class);        
        Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
        while(iteratorTags.hasNext()){
            disjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("tagId", iteratorTags.next().getTagId()));
        }
        criteriaForTag.add(disjunction);
        criteriaForTag.setProjection(Property.forName("newsId"));

        DetachedCriteria criteriaForAuthor = DetachedCriteria.forClass(NewsAuthor.class);
        criteriaForAuthor.add( Property.forName("authorId").eq(filter.getAuthor().
                getAuthorId()) );
        criteriaForAuthor.setProjection(Property.forName("newsId"));

        criteriaForNewsByAuthor = DetachedCriteria.forClass(News.class)
            .add(Restrictions.or(
                Property.forName("newsId").in(criteriaForTag),
                Property.forName("newsId").in(criteriaForAuthor))
            );
    }
    return criteriaForNewsByAuthor;
}
```

Am i right?

Comment: Try to test this method. Convert result of this method to Criteria using getExecutableCriteria(Session session) and do list() for it. I think it will be better if you move disjunction creation code (with while) to other helper method and check an author name and tags for emptiness (if condition) in method that calls getCreteriaForFiltering().